# Refactoring Ajax code resulted in missing error

Tags: javascript, ajax

I wanted to make my code smaller and more compact , so I refactored it to best of my knowledge. Now on success Ajax function should call function `someface` on failure it should raise an error.

```js
//functions.js
//ajax constructor
var AJAX = (new XMLHttpRequest()) || (new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")) || (new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"));
AJAX.load = function (filename,call_function,async,method,string_toSend) {
    //making default value for ajax.load method
    method          = typeof method !== 'undefined' ? method : 'GET';
    async           = typeof async !== 'undefined' ? async : true;
    string_toSend   = typeof string_toSend !== 'undefined' ? string_toSend : null;
    if (AJAX.readyState == 4 && AJAX.status == 200) {
       call_function;
    }
    AJAX.open(method,filename,async);
    AJAX.send(string_toSend);
}


//general.js
//making AJAX object
var navigation = AJAX;
navigation.load("xml/content.xml",someface);

//not displaying ?? why ?
var someface = function (){
    console.log('you are a someface');
}
```

```html
<!-- scripts -->
<script src = "javascirpt/functions.js" ></script>
<script src = "javascirpt/general.js" ></script>
```

To test this, there are 2 js files ... `functions.js` that hold callable functions, and `general.js` that holds all Ajax calls that I can use.

**The issue is that no error and no "you are some face" are displayed in console. **.

I combed through code for the last of 2-3 hours, and I can't find the bug. Does anyone see what I don't see?

Comment: `javascirpt/functions.js` typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are a lot of fixes you have to do. First of all, you have to create a listener for the readystatechange event. Then, you are calling your load function with "someface" argument BEFORE you define someface. The result is that in AJAX context, someface is undefined.

Here is the updated code sample

```
var AJAX = (new XMLHttpRequest()) || (new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")) || (new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"));
AJAX.load = function (filename,call_function,async,method,string_toSend) {
    //making default value for ajax.load method
    method = typeof method !== 'undefined' ? method : 'GET';
    async = typeof async !== 'undefined' ? async : true;
    string_toSend   = typeof string_toSend !== 'undefined' ? string_toSend : null;
    AJAX.open(method,filename,async);
    AJAX.send(string_toSend);
    //event handler
    AJAX.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (AJAX.readyState == 4 && AJAX.status == 200) {
            call_function();
        }
    };
};

//we define someface BEFORE you call navigation.load();
var someface = function (){
    console.log('you are a someface');
};
//general.js
//making AJAX object
var navigation = AJAX;
navigation.load("/test.php",someface);
```

Comment: i changed the code to call_function(), and tried to make function someface  - did not work. I also tried to store that function into object , such as var a = function (){cosole.log('blablalba');} still did not work. i tried to change ajax.load method to accept function not call_function variable still nothing ... well in short for every probability of 1 in 4 i tired and still it does not make log in console ('you are a someface'). Did you try to run it? WIll it execute in your enviorment?

Comment: i am sorry... i am stupid as hell. just saw that... i figured that if console does not report an error the main code is ok.... dumb dumb me. 
another quesiton, i saw that some people have call back in the if where AJAX.readystate == 4 etc etc where they call for timeout of 1 second and call function again... would it be possible that call something like 
timeout('ajax.load('+filename+','+call_function+';' , 1000) ?

Comment: Well, i don't know if i understood your last question. By the way, basically you can use the setTimeout javascript in combination with the apply or bind or call methods.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call